# To change the color of table rows based on similar records

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jsp

I have a List of applications displayed in jsp page. I want all the records having same id to be in one color.Example: records having Id 1 should be in grey color and records of Id 2 should be in green etc..Please help to solve this using css/javascript/jquery. 
[displayApp.jsp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3OTe.png)

Comment: and what have you tried so far?

Comment: Please post your code in the question. An image of the output is unfortunately of no use to anyone.

Comment: Paste your code of what you tried so far....

Comment: Just give the same class to the same records and write css accordingly

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly following will help you :-

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var colors = mapColursToText()
  mapColursToTr(colors)

});

function mapColursToText() {
  var colors = [];

  $('table').find('tr').find('td:first').each(function() {
    if (colors.length == 0) {
      colors.push(new Array($(this).text(), getRandomColor()));
    } else {
      for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
        console.log()
        if (colors[i][0].toLowerCase().indexOf($(this).text().toLowerCase()) <= -1) {
          colors.push(new Array($(this).text(), getRandomColor()));
        }
      }
    }
  });
  return colors
}

function mapColursToTr(colors) {
  for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; ++i) {
    $('table').find('tr').find('td:first').filter(function() {
      return $(this).text() === colors[i][0];
    }).each(function() {
      $(this).parents('tr').css({
        'color': colors[i][1]
      });
    });
  }
}

function getRandomColor() {
  var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
  var color = '#';
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }
  return color;
}
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Company</th>
        <th>Contact</th>
        <th>Country</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
        <td>Maria Anders</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
        <td>Maria Anders</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
        <td>Maria Anders</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
        <td>Francisco Chang</td>
        <td>Mexico</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Ernst Handel</td>
        <td>Roland Mendel</td>
        <td>Austria</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Island Trading</td>
        <td>Helen Bennett</td>
        <td>UK</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
        <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
        <td>Canada</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
        <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
        <td>Italy</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```